# Temporarily Disable Rprofile

Tags: r, rstudio, rprofile

How do I temporarily disable Rprofile. short of renaming the file? Is there an elegant way to toggle my Rprofile on and off upon startup of RStudio?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is easily done without RStudio by launching R from the command line. You can either launch R with the `--no-init-file` flag to load without `.Rprofile`.

Another option is to have an alternative `.Rprofile` in the folder you are launching R from. For example, I have a folder called "update_R" where I have an `.Rprofile` that doesn't load any packages on startup and runs `update.packages`. At startup, R first looks for `.Rprofile.site`, then for `.Rprofile` in the working directory, then finally for `.Rprofile` in the user directory.

For RStudio, the only way to do this appears to be to use a Project and to place a special `.Rprofle` within the project folder. Hope this helps.